# Return boolean with ternary operator

Tags: c

I made this code to know if my input is a multiple of two

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

bool    main(int ac, char **av)
{
  if (ac == 2)
  {
      int nb = atoi(av[1]);
      (((nb / 2) * 2) != nb) ? false : true; 
  }
}
```

But gcc is returning me this :

```
test.c:5:1: error: unknown type name ‘bool’
bool main(int ac, char **av)
^
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:10:32: error: ‘false’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   (((nb / 2) * 2) != nb) ? false : true;
                            ^
test.c:10:32: note: each undeclared identifier is reported only once for each function it appears in
test.c:10:40: error: ‘true’ undeclared (first use in this function)
   (((nb / 2) * 2) != nb) ? false : true;
```

I'm under *Ubuntu bash for Windows* (I haven't access to any Linux now)

I don't understand why I can't use **bool** type for my function, or why '**false**' and '**true**' aren't recognised

Comment: you are missing the `return` statement.

Comment: also include `stdbool.h` to use `bool`.

Comment: `main` doesn't return a `bool`. Considering the number of issues you have in this short program, you are better off reading your book first.

Comment: I'm confused...unclear or too broad?

Comment: The C specification says that `main` must return an `int`.

Comment: Tried with return, it did the same
Didn't know that main can't return something else than int, thanks

Comment: You can simplify `(((nb / 2) * 2) != nb)` to `nb & 1`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have a number of issues in your code.

First of all you miss the `return` keyword here:

```
return (((nb / 2) * 2) != nb) ? false : true;
^^^^^^
```

Besides that you don't need a ternary operator as the first part is all ready a bool. So simply do:

```
return (((nb / 2) * 2) == nb);
^^^^^^                 ^^
```

Further you don't have a `return` statement in the code when `ac` isn't equal 2.

Also you should include `stdbool.h` to use `bool`.

Finally the `main` function must return an `int` - not a `bool`.

A rewrite of your code could be:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdbool.h>   // Include this to use bool

bool foo(int ac, char **av)
{
  if (ac == 2)
  {
      int nb = atoi(av[1]);
      return (((nb / 2) * 2) == nb); 
  }

  return false;
}

int main(int ac, char **av)
{
    if (foo(ac, av))
    {
        printf("foo returned true\n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("foo returned false\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all I want to say, that instead of this,

```
(((nb / 2) * 2) != nb) ? false : true;
```

you could always use

```
!(((nb / 2) * 2) != nb)
```

(ofc == nb will also do the trick)

If the compiler doesnt recognize the true and false, than most likely you have some problems with your code, maybe u've broken the syntax or made somehow compiler go crazy and it throws this kind of errors. Dont see any other reaso

Comment: Answer is missing an important bit about `stdbool.h`.